# PHP: exec('echo "hi" > /tmp/output.txt') Is Not Creating a File

Tags: php, security, apache2

The following line of code executes properly, but does not generate "output.txt" within the "temp" directory. It also doesn't have any errors.

exec('echo "hi" > /tmp/output.txt', $o, $r);

This used to work on a Debian 8 system about a year ago, but stopped working after we did an apt-get update && apt-get upgrade. Does anyone know what changed that would cause this so I can turn it off/undo it? The user www-data has permissions to create in the tmp directory, and that is what the web server is running as.

Since I'm sure someone will immediately jump on this and say, "But why would you do it this way", let me explain. [There is a purposely vulnerable WebApp called WackoPico](https://github.com/adamdoupe/WackoPicko) that I use in a WebApp Ethical Hacking class. In it there is a [command injection vulnerability](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Command_Injection) that I have labs that the students exploit.

As a proof-of-concept of the injection vulnerability they do something similar to the line of code displayed above, to show they can execute commands.

I have no doubt that the above sort of code was prevented from working due to some very good security update or setting in Apache or PHP. However, for my particular purposes I need to "undo" this for instructional purposes.

-- EDIT To Clarify a Few Things ---

To troubleshoot the problem I modified one of the PHP files to literally have the following line of code. I'm not trying to execute the command injection vulnerability. I'm assuming if I resolve this, it will resolve the other:

```
exec('echo "hi" > /tmp/output.txt', $o, $r);
```

The values of $o and $r respectively from var_dump are:

```
array[0]{}
int[0]
```

If I run the following, it creates the file as expected:

```
sudo -u www-data echo "hi" > /tmp/output.txt
```

My php info is the following:

```
PHP Version 5.6.22-1

System  Linux ninjutsu 3.16.0-4-686-pae #1 S MP Debian 3.16.43-2+deb8u2 (2017-06-26) i686
Server API  Apache 2.0 Handler
Virtual Directory Support   disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc/php5 /apache2
Loaded Configuration File   /etc/php5/apache2 /php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files /et c/php5/apache2/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed    /etc/php5/apac he2/conf.d/05-opcache.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/10-pdo.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-gd.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-json.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mysql.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-readline.ini
PHP API 20131106
PHP Extension   20131226
Zend Extension  220131226
Zend Extension Build    API220131226,NTS
PHP Extension Build API20131226,NTS
Debug Build no
Thread Safety   disabled
Zend Signal Handling    disabled
Zend Memory Manager enabled
Zend Multibyte Support  provided by mbstring
IPv6 Support    enabled
DTrace Support  enabled
Registered PHP Streams  https, ftps, compress .zlib, compress.bzip2, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, phar, zip
Registered Stream Socket Transports tcp, udp , unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, tls, tlsv1.0, tlsv1.1, tlsv1.2
Registered Stream Filters   zlib.*, bzip2.*, c onvert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk
Zend logo This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Eng ine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technolog ies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev,&nb sp;Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
< /td>
Configuration

apache2handler

Apache Version  Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)
Apache API Version  20120211
Server Administrator    [no address given]
Hostname:Port   wacko.local:0
User/Group  www-data(33)/33
Max Requests    Per Child: 0 - Keep Alive: on - Max Per Connection: 100
Timeouts    Connection: 300 - Keep-Alive: 5
Virtual Server  Yes
Server Root /etc/apache2
Loaded Modules  core mod_so mod_watchdog htt p_core mod_log_config mod_logio mod_version mod_unixd mod_access_compat mod_alia s mod_auth_basic mod_authn_core mod_authn_file mod_authz_core mod_authz_host mod _authz_user mod_autoindex mod_deflate mod_dir mod_env mod_filter mod_mime prefor k mod_negotiation mod_php5 mod_proxy mod_proxy_http mod_reqtimeout mod_rewrite m od_setenvif mod_status
Directive   Local Value Master Value
engine  1   1
last_modified   0   0
xbithack    0   0
Apache Environment

Variable    Value
HTTP_HOST   wacko.local
HTTP_USER_AGENT curl/7.47.0
HTTP_ACCEPT */*
PATH    /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sb in:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
SERVER_SIGNATURE    <address>Apache/2.4. 25 (Debian) Server at wacko.local Port 80</address>
SERVER_SOFTWARE Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)
SERVER_NAME wacko.local
SERVER_ADDR 127.0.0.1
SERVER_PORT 80
REMOTE_ADDR 127.0.0.1
DOCUMENT_ROOT   /var/www/wacko.local/website/
REQUEST_SCHEME  http
CONTEXT_PREFIX  no value
CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT   /var/www/wacko.local/ website/
SERVER_ADMIN    [no address given]
SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/wacko.local/websit e/phpinfo.php
REMOTE_PORT 42885
GATEWAY_INTERFACE   CGI/1.1
SERVER_PROTOCOL HTTP/1.1
REQUEST_METHOD  GET
QUERY_STRING    no value
REQUEST_URI /phpinfo.php
SCRIPT_NAME /phpinfo.php
HTTP Headers Information

HTTP Request Headers
HTTP Request    GET /phpinfo.php HTTP/1.1
Host    wacko.local
User-Agent  curl/7.47.0
Accept  */*
HTTP Response Headers
bcmath

BCMath support  enabled
Directive   Local Value Master Value
bcmath.scale    0   0
bz2

BZip2 Support   Enabled
Stream Wrapper support  compress.bzip2://
Stream Filter support   bzip2.decompress, bzi p2.compress
BZip2 Version   1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010
calendar

Calendar support    enabled
Core

PHP Version 5.6.22-1
< /tr> < /tr> < /tr>
Directive   Local Value Master Value
allow_url_fopen On  On
allow_url_include   Off Off< /td>
always_populate_raw_post_data   0   0
arg_separator.input &   &
arg_separator.output    &   &
asp_tags    Off Off
auto_append_file    no value    no value
auto_globals_jit    On  On
auto_prepend_file   no value    no value
browscap    no value    < i>no value
default_charset UTF-8   UTF- 8
default_mimetype    text/html   text/html
disable_classes no value    no value
disable_functions   pcntl_alarm,pcntl_fork,pcn tl_waitpid,pcntl_wait,pcntl_wifexited,pcntl_wifstopped,pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_w exitstatus,pcntl_wtermsig,pcntl_wstopsig,pcntl_signal,pcntl_signal_dispatch,pcnt l_get_last_error,pcntl_strerror,pcntl_sigprocmask,pcntl_sigwaitinfo,pcntl_sigtim edwait,pcntl_exec,pcntl_getpriority,pcntl_setpriority,    pcntl_a larm,pcntl_fork,pcntl_waitpid,pcntl_wait,pcntl_wifexited,pcntl_wifstopped,pcntl_ wifsignaled,pcntl_wexitstatus,pcntl_wtermsig,pcntl_wstopsig,pcntl_signal,pcntl_s ignal_dispatch,pcntl_get_last_error,pcntl_strerror,pcntl_sigprocmask,pcntl_sigwa itinfo,pcntl_sigtimedwait,pcntl_exec,pcntl_getpriority,pcntl_setpriority,
display_errors  Off Off
display_startup_errors  Off Off
doc_root    no value    < i>no value
docref_ext  no value    no value
docref_root no value    no value
enable_dl   Off Off
enable_post_data_reading    On  On
error_append_string no value    no value
error_log   no value    no value
error_prepend_string    no value    no value
error_reporting 22527   2252 7
exit_on_timeout Off Off
expose_php  Off Off
extension_dir   /usr/lib/php5/20131226  /usr/lib/php5/20131226
file_uploads    On  On
highlight.comment   #FF8000 #FF8000< /td>
highlight.default   #0000BB #0000BB< /td>
highlight.html  #000000 #000000
highlight.keyword   #007700 #007700< /td>
highlight.string    #DD0000 #DD0000
html_errors On  On
ignore_repeated_errors  Off Off
ignore_repeated_source  Off Off
ignore_user_abort   Off Off< /td>
implicit_flush  Off Off
include_path    .:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pea r:  .:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:
input_encoding  no value    no value
internal_encoding   no value    no value
log_errors  On  On
log_errors_max_len  1024    10 24
mail.add_x_header   On  On
mail.force_extra_parameters no value< /td>  no value
mail.log    no value    < i>no value
max_execution_time  30  30
max_file_uploads    20  20
max_input_nesting_level 64  64
max_input_time  60  60
max_input_vars  1000    1000
memory_limit    128M    128M
open_basedir    no value    no value
output_buffering    4096    4096
output_encoding no value    no value
output_handler  no value    no value
post_max_size   8M  8M
precision   14  14
realpath_cache_size 16K 16 K
realpath_cache_ttl  120 120
register_argc_argv  Off Off
report_memleaks On  On
report_zend_debug   On  On
request_order   GP  GP
sendmail_from   no value    no value
sendmail_path   /usr/sbin/sendmail -t&nbs p;-i  /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i 
serialize_precision 17  17< /td>
short_open_tag  On  Off
SMTP    localhost   localhost
smtp_port   25  25
sql.safe_mode   Off Off
sys_temp_dir    no value    no value
track_errors    Off Off
unserialize_callback_func   no value    no value
upload_max_filesize 2M  2M< /td>
upload_tmp_dir  no value    no value
user_dir    no value    < i>no value
user_ini.cache_ttl  300 300
user_ini.filename   .user.ini   .user.ini
variables_order GPCS    GPCS< /td>
xmlrpc_error_number 0   0
xmlrpc_errors   Off Off
zend.detect_unicode On  On< /td>
zend.enable_gc  On  On
zend.multibyte  Off Off
zend.script_encoding    no value    no value
ctype

ctype functions enabled
date

date/time support   enabled
"Olson" Timezone Database Version   0.system
Timezone Database   internal
Default timezone    America/New_York
Directive   Local Value Master Value
date.default_latitude   31.7667 31.7667
date.default_longitude  35.2333 35.2333
date.sunrise_zenith 90.583333   90.583333
date.sunset_zenith  90.583333   90.583333
date.timezone   no value    no value
dba

DBA support enabled
libdb header version    Berkeley DB 5.3.28: (S eptember 9, 2013)
libdb library version   Berkeley DB 5.3.28: ( September 9, 2013)
Supported handlers  cdb cdb_make db4 inifile flatfile qdbm
Directive   Local Value Master Value
dba.default_handler flatfile    flatfile
dom

DOM/XML enabled
DOM/XML API Version 20031129
libxml Version  2.9.3
HTML Support    enabled
XPath Support   enabled
XPointer Support    enabled
Schema Support  enabled
RelaxNG Support enabled
ereg

Regex Library   Bundled library enabled
exif

EXIF Support    enabled
EXIF Version    1.4 $Id: db007ca2e6d0b4513ae77 990972997fad8bfe9c9 $
Supported EXIF Version  0220
Supported filetypes JPEG,TIFF
Directive   Local Value Master Value
exif.decode_jis_intel   JIS JIS
exif.decode_jis_motorola    JIS JIS
exif.decode_unicode_intel   UCS-2LE UCS-2LE
exif.decode_unicode_motorola    UCS-2BE UCS-2BE
exif.encode_jis no value    no value
exif.encode_unicode ISO-8859-15 ISO-8859-15
fileinfo

fileinfo support    enabled
version 1.0.5
libmagic    517
filter

Input Validation and Filtering  enabled
Revision    $Id: 0a967738ca580e8bfdacb06853749 743fc79b969 $
Directive   Local Value Master Value
filter.default  unsafe_raw  unsafe_raw
filter.default_flags    no value    no value
ftp

FTP support enabled
gd

GD Support  enabled
GD headers Version  2.2.1
GD library Version  2.2.1
FreeType Support    enabled
FreeType Linkage    with freetype
FreeType Version    2.6.3
GIF Read Support    enabled
GIF Create Support  enabled
JPEG Support    enabled
libJPEG Version 6b
PNG Support enabled
libPNG Version  1.6.21
WBMP Support    enabled
XPM Support enabled
libXpm Version  30411
XBM Support enabled
WebP Support    enabled
Directive   Local Value Master Value
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning  0   0
gettext

GetText Support enabled
hash

hash support    enabled
Hashing Engines md2 md4 md5 sha1 sha224 sha 256 sha384 sha512 ripemd128 ripemd160 ripemd256 ripemd320 whirlpool tiger128,3 t iger160,3 tiger192,3 tiger128,4 tiger160,4 tiger192,4 snefru snefru256 gost gost -crypto adler32 crc32 crc32b fnv132 fnv1a32 fnv164 fnv1a64 joaat haval128,3 hava l160,3 haval192,3 haval224,3 haval256,3 haval128,4 haval160,4 haval192,4 haval22 4,4 haval256,4 haval128,5 haval160,5 haval192,5 haval224,5 haval256,5
iconv

iconv support   enabled
iconv implementation    glibc
iconv library version   2.24
no value
Directive   Local Value Master Value
iconv.input_encoding    no value    no value
iconv.internal_encoding no value    no value
iconv.output_encoding   no value
json

json support    enabled
json version    1.3.9
JSON-C version (bundled)    0.11
libxml

libXML support  active
libXML Compiled Version 2.9.3
libXML Loaded Version   20903
libXML streams  enabled
mbstring

Multibyte Support   enabled
Multibyte string engine libmbfl
HTTP input encoding translation disabled
libmbfl version 1.3.2
mbstring extension makes use of "streamable kanji code filter and converter", which is distributed under the GNU Lesser General Public License version 2.1.
Multibyte (japanese) regex support  enabled
Multibyte regex (oniguruma) version 5.9.6 < /td>
no value
Directive   Local Value Master Value
mbstring.detect_order   no value
mbstring.encoding_translation   Off Off
mbstring.func_overload  0   0
mbstring.http_input no value    no value
mbstring.http_output    no value    no value
mbstring.http_output_conv_mimetypes ^(text/| application/xhtml\+xml)    ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml)
mbstring.internal_encoding  no value    no value
mbstring.language   neutral neutral
mbstring.strict_detection   Off Off
mbstring.substitute_character   no value    no value
mhash

MHASH support   Enabled
MHASH API Version   Emulated Support
mysql

MySQL Support   enabled
Active Persistent Links 0
Active Links    0
Client API version  5.6.30
MYSQL_MODULE_TYPE   external
MYSQL_SOCKET    /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
MYSQL_INCLUDE   -I/usr/include/mysql
MYSQL_LIBS  -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -lmysq lclient_r
< td class="v">no value
Directive   Local Value Master Value
mysql.allow_local_infile    On  On
mysql.allow_persistent  On  On
mysql.connect_timeout   60  6 0
mysql.default_host  no value    no value
mysql.default_password  no value
mysql.default_port  no value    no value
mysql.default_socket    /var/run/mysqld/mysqld. sock    /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
mysql.default_user  no value    no value
mysql.max_links Unlimited   Unlimited
mysql.max_persistent    Unlimited   Unlimited
mysql.trace_mode    Off Off
mysqli

MysqlI Support  enabled
Client API library version  5.6.30
Active Persistent Links 0
Inactive Persistent Links   0
Active Links    0
Client API header version   5.6.30
MYSQLI_SOCKET   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock < /td>
Directive   Local Value Master Value
mysqli.allow_local_infile   On  On
mysqli.allow_persistent On  On
mysqli.default_host no value    no value
mysqli.default_port 3306    3 306
mysqli.default_pw   no value    no value
mysqli.default_socket   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld .sock    /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
mysqli.default_user no value    no value
mysqli.max_links    Unlimited   Unlimited
mysqli.max_persistent   Unlimited   Unlimited
mysqli.reconnect    Off Off
mysqli.rollback_on_cached_plink Off Off
openssl

OpenSSL support enabled
OpenSSL Library Version OpenSSL 1.0.2l 25 May 2017
OpenSSL Header Version  OpenSSL 1.0.2h 3 Ma y 2016
Openssl default config  /usr/lib/ssl/openssl .cnf
Directive   Local Value Master Value
openssl.cafile  no value    no value
openssl.capath  no value    no value
pcre

< /tr>
PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) Support  enabled
PCRE Library Version    8.39 2016-06-14
Directive   Local Value Master Value
pcre.backtrack_limit    1000000 1000000
pcre.recursion_limit    100000  100000
PDO

PDO support enabled
PDO drivers mysql
pdo_mysql

PDO Driver for MySQL    enabled
Client API version  5.6.30
Directive   Local Value Master Value
pdo_mysql.default_socket    /var/run/mysqld/mys qld.sock    /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Phar

Phar: PHP Archive support   enabled
Phar EXT version    2.0.2
Phar API version    1.1.1
SVN revision    $Id: 14b80e175ed4d5bf11c890e1f 30ea8225935b16c $
Phar-based phar archives    enabled
Tar-based phar archives enabled
ZIP-based phar archives enabled
gzip compression    enabled
bzip2 compression   enabled
OpenSSL support enabled
Phar based on pear/PHP_Archive, original concept by Davey Shafik.
Phar full y realized by Gregory Beaver and Marcus Boerger.
Portions of tar implementa tion Copyright (c) 2003-2009 Tim Kientzle.
Directive   Local Value Master Value
phar.cache_list no value    no value
phar.readonly   On  On
phar.require_hash   On  On
posix

Revision    $Id: 5f4acc20904b1406142f2a0ede068 db048c77e77 $
readline

Readline Support    enabled
Readline library    EditLine wrapper
Directive   Local Value Master Value
cli.pager   no value    no value
cli.prompt  \b \>   \b \> 
Reflection

Reflection  enabled
Version $Id: fbcf7a77ca8e3d4cd7501de8025235 b947b8240f $
session

< /tr>
Session Support enabled
Registered save handlers    files user
Registered serializer handlers  php_serializ e php php_binary wddx
no valueno value
Directive   Local Value Master Value
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.cache_expire    180 1 80
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value
session.cookie_httponly Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    /dev/urandom    /dev/urandom
session.entropy_length  32  32
session.gc_divisor  1000    10 00
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
session.gc_probability  0   0
session.hash_bits_per_character 5   5
session.hash_function   0   0< /td>
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHP SESSID
session.referer_check   no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   /var/lib/php5/sessions  /var/lib/php5/sessions
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.upload_progress.cleanup On  On
session.upload_progress.enabled On  On
session.upload_progress.freq    1%  1%
session.upload_progress.min_freq    1   1
session.upload_progress.name    PHP_SESSION_UPL OAD_PROGRESS    PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
session.upload_progress.prefix  upload_progre ss_   upload_progress_
session.use_cookies On  On< /td>
session.use_only_cookies    On  On
session.use_strict_mode Off Off
session.use_trans_sid   0   0< /td>
shmop

shmop support   enabled
SimpleXML

Simplexml support   enabled
Revision    $Id: 07fc6546e896094aed794aea4691f 0151774d955 $
Schema support  enabled
soap

Soap Client enabled
Soap Server enabled
Directive   Local Value Master Value
soap.wsdl_cache 1   1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir /tmp    / tmp
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled 1   1
soap.wsdl_cache_limit   5   5< /td>
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl 86400   86400
sockets

Sockets Support enabled
SPL

SPL support enabled
Interfaces  Countable, OuterIterator, Recurs iveIterator, SeekableIterator, SplObserver, SplSubject
Classes AppendIterator, ArrayIterator, Arra yObject, BadFunctionCallException, BadMethodCallException, CachingIterator, Call backFilterIterator, DirectoryIterator, DomainException, EmptyIterator, Filesyste mIterator, FilterIterator, GlobIterator, InfiniteIterator, InvalidArgumentExcept ion, IteratorIterator, LengthException, LimitIterator, LogicException, MultipleI terator, NoRewindIterator, OutOfBoundsException, OutOfRangeException, OverflowEx ception, ParentIterator, RangeException, RecursiveArrayIterator, RecursiveCachin gIterator, RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator, RecursiveDirectoryIterator, Recursiv eFilterIterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator, RecursiveRegexIterator, RecursiveTre eIterator, RegexIterator, RuntimeException, SplDoublyLinkedList, SplFileInfo, Sp lFileObject, SplFixedArray, SplHeap, SplMinHeap, SplMaxHeap, SplObjectStorage, S plPriorityQueue, SplQueue, SplStack, SplTempFileObject, UnderflowException, Unex pectedValueException
standard

Dynamic Library Support enabled
Path to sendmail    /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
Directive   Local Value Master Value
assert.active   1   1
assert.bail 0   0
assert.callback no value    no value
assert.quiet_eval   0   0
assert.warning  1   1
auto_detect_line_endings    0   0
default_socket_timeout  60  60
from    no value    no value
url_rewriter.tags   a=href,area=href,frame=src ,input=src,form=fakeentry    a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src ,form=fakeentry
user_agent  no value    no value
sysvmsg

sysvmsg support enabled
Revision    $Id: 58590192720bc56939152fde3645d 808b348bb9b $
tokenizer

Tokenizer Support   enabled
wddx

WDDX Support    enabled
WDDX Session Serializer enabled
xml

XML Support active
XML Namespace Support   active
libxml2 Version 2.9.3
xmlreader

XMLReader   enabled
xmlwriter

XMLWriter   enabled
Zend OPcache

< /tr>
Opcode Caching  Up and Running
Optimization    Enabled
Startup OK
Shared memory model mmap
Cache hits  160
Cache misses    32
Used memory 5494484
Free memory 61603728
Wasted memory   10652
Interned Strings Used memory    289980
Interned Strings Free memory    3904324
Cached scripts  28
Cached keys 44
Max keys    3907
OOM restarts    0
Hash keys restarts  0
Manual restarts 0
< /tr> 0x7FFFBFFF
Directive   Local Value Master Value
opcache.blacklist_filename  no value    no value
opcache.consistency_checks  0   0
opcache.dups_fix    Off Off
opcache.enable  On  On
opcache.enable_cli  Off Off
opcache.enable_file_override    Off Off
opcache.error_log   no value    no value
opcache.fast_shutdown   0   0< /td>
opcache.file_update_protection  2   2
opcache.force_restart_timeout   180 180
opcache.inherited_hack  On  On
opcache.interned_strings_buffer 4   4
opcache.load_comments   1   1< /td>
opcache.lockfile_path   /tmp    /tmp
opcache.log_verbosity_level 1   1
opcache.max_accelerated_files   2000    2000
opcache.max_file_size   0   0< /td>
opcache.max_wasted_percentage   5   5
opcache.memory_consumption  64  64
opcache.optimization_level  0x7FFFBFFF
opcache.preferred_memory_model  no value    no value
opcache.protect_memory  0   0
opcache.restrict_api    no value    no value
opcache.revalidate_freq 2   2
opcache.revalidate_path Off Off
opcache.save_comments   1   1< /td>
opcache.use_cwd On  On
opcache.validate_timestamps On  On
zip

Zip enabled
Zip version 1.12.5
Libzip version  0.11.2
zlib

ZLib Support    enabled
Stream Wrapper  compress.zlib://
Stream Filter   zlib.inflate, zlib.deflate
Compiled Version    1.2.8
Linked Version  1.2.8
Directive   Local Value Master Value
zlib.output_compression Off Off
zlib.output_compression_level   -1  -1
zlib.output_handler no value    no value
Additional Modules

Module Name
sysvsem
sysvshm
Environment

Variable    Value
APACHE_RUN_DIR  /var/run/apache2
APACHE_PID_FILE /var/run/apache2/apache2.pi d
PATH    /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sb in:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
APACHE_LOCK_DIR /var/lock/apache2
LANG    C
APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
APACHE_RUN_GROUP    www-data
APACHE_LOG_DIR  /var/log/apache2
PWD /
PHP Variables

< /tr>
Variable    Value
_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]    wacko.local
_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]  curl/7.47.0
_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT"]  */*
_SERVER["PATH"] /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/b in:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
_SERVER["SERVER_SIGNATURE"] <address>A pache/2.4.25 (Debian) Server at wacko.local Port 80</address>
_SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]  Apache/2.4.25 (De bian)
_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]  wacko.local
_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"]  127.0.0.1
_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]  80
_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]  127.0.0.1
_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]    /var/www/wacko.loca l/website/
_SERVER["REQUEST_SCHEME"]   http
_SERVER["CONTEXT_PREFIX"]   no value
_SERVER["CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT"]    /var/www/wa cko.local/website/
_SERVER["SERVER_ADMIN"] [no address given]
_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]  /var/www/wacko.lo cal/website/phpinfo.php
_SERVER["REMOTE_PORT"]  42885
_SERVER["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"]    CGI/1.1
_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]  HTTP/1.1
_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]   GET
_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] no value
_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]  /phpinfo.php
_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]  /phpinfo.php
_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] /phpinfo.php
_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]   1499394501.793
_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME"] 1499394501
```

Per the above, my error_log value is "null" therefore errors should be in Apache2's error.log in /var/log/apache2 . That log does not have any new entries when I run my page.

---- EDIT AGAIN WITH MORE DETAILS & CLOSER TO ISOLATING ------

Okay, so if I run apache this way it creates the file when I hit the PHP page:

```
apachectl -f /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

If I run Apache this way, it does not create the file:

```
apachectl start
```

Comment: Is this a command in your plain PHP code, or are you trying to exploit the command injection vulnerability?

Comment: Have you checked the error logs to make sure the code is executing properly? If something failed, that would definitely tell you what it was such as permissions or other. You say it is, but if nothing is happening, I tend to believe it isn't working.

Comment: To troubleshoot I put that code as listed directly into the php file to test and it didn't work as listed. Apache's error log is blank for the request, and there are no errors or output in $o or $r.

Comment: @Doug depending on how PHP is configured, it may not be using apache's error log. Run `phpinfo();` to see what error_log is using.

Comment: @mkaatman error_log is null, which this seems to suggest errors should then be in the Apache logs.
http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Yes, error logs were checked and have no output. That's one of the first things I looked at.

Comment: Can you su - www-data and run the command directly?

Comment: @mkaatman Yes, and it runs properly and creates the file.

Comment: Is rolling back the apt dist-upgrade an option?

Comment: @mkaatman Systematically rolling back packages is what I will start tomorrow to further isolate the issue. Since its been a year since I taught this class there is a solid 500+ updates though, so I was hoping someone would have an idea what it could be so I could hopefully make individual changes easier.

Comment: Does this work from cli as www-data? `php -r "exec('echo \"hi\" > /tmp/output.txt');"`

Comment: Maybe at the top of your script set: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: @mkaatman Great suggestions! Thanks! php -r 'exec' etc, outputs the file as it should. This implies its something with Apache. Nothing new revealed with the ini settings and error reporting though. I'll have to see if I can zero in on what changed in Apache.

Comment: For whatever it's worth, I tried this on my ubuntu 16.04 vm with apache 2.4 php 7.1 and it worked fine.

Comment: @mkaatman Are you running 2.4.25?

Comment: Okay, I'm getting closer... if I run Apache this way, the file is created on the hitting of the page:
apachectl -f /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Comment: Arg, the daemon uses the same exact config file. I don't understand what could be different.

Comment: I'm running: `Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2017-06-26T11:58:04`

Comment: Any possibility you could spin up a VM with virtualbox or the like for the purposes of training and see if you get better results?

Comment: @mkaatman This fortunately is already a VM and I have snapshots to go back to.